# Set Path of .desktop file to run a executable in same directory

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to create a .desktop file for running a python script. This is my current code,

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Version=1.0  
Name=AronzSmartBell  
Comment=This is my comment  
Exec= python /home/arun/PycharmProjects/smartbell/jojulogin_mod.py  
Path=/home/arun/PycharmProjects/smartbell/  
Terminal=false  
Type=Application  
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

In the above code I need to specify full path of python file in the `Exec` statement like
`Exec= python /home/arun/PycharmProjects/smartbell/jojulogin_mod.py`.In my  case python file and .desktop file is in same directory.So there is any way to specify the Exec path to directory which .desktop file placed??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144422/getting-the-current-path-in-desktop-exec-command), If the `python` file (.py) is in the same directory as the `.desktop` file, just use relative paths as shown below:

```
Exec= python ./jojulogin_mod.py
```